# Is any difference between zip two and more than two lists?

Tags: python, python-2.7, zip, linear-regression

I think that it's a very subtle issue, maybe an unknown bug in Python2.7. I'm making an interactive application. It should fit WLS (Weighted Linear Regression) model to the cloud of points. At the beginning the script reads the data from a text file (just a simple table with indexes, values and errors of each point). But in the data could be some points with NULL value marked by `nocompl=99.9999`. I have to know which these points are to reject them before the script starts the fitting. I do this in the following way:

```
# read the data from input file
Bunchlst = [Bunch(val1 = D[:,i], err_val1 = D[:,i+1], val2 = D[:,i+2], err_val2 = D[:,i+3]) for i in range(1, D.shape[1] - 1, 4)]

# here is the problem
for b in Bunchlst:
    b.compl = list(np.logical_not([1 if nocompl in [im,ie,sm,se] else 0 for v1,e1,v2,e2 in zip(b.val1,b.err_val1,b.val2,b.err_val2)]))

# fit the model to the "good" points
wls = sm.WLS(list(compress(b.val1,b.compl)), sm.add_constant(list(compress(b.val2,b.compl)), prepend=False), weights=[1.0/i for i in list(compress(b.err_val2,b.compl))]).fit()
```

[WLS model implemented in Python](http://statsmodels.sourceforge.net/devel/generated/statsmodels.regression.linear_model.WLS.html).`compress()` allows to filter the data (omitting NULL values). But this case generates the bug:

> wls = sm.WLS(...).fit()
>   AttributeError: 'numpy.float64' object has no attribute 'WLS'

I made an investigation and when I zip only two lists, the problem disappears and WLS model computes itself correctly:

```
for b in Bunchlst:
    b.compl = list(np.logical_not([1 if nocompl in [v1,v2] else 0 for v1,v2 in zip(b.val1,b.val2)]))
```

I wrote, that probably it may be a bug, because I checked `b.compl` in both cases. Always there were the same lists with `True` or `False` values (depending on the data from input file). Moreover, simple considerations lead to that it has to work for many lists:

```
>>> K = [11, 12, 13, 14, 15, 16, 17, 18, 19, 20]
>>> L = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10]
>>> M = [21, 22, 23, 24, 25, 26, 27, 28, 29, 30]
>>> N = [32, 33, 34, 35, 36, 37, 38, 39, 40, 32]

>>> [1 if 26 in [k,l,m,n] else 0 for k,l,m,n in zip(K,L,M,N)]
[0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0]
```

All the best,

Benek

Comment: Where are you setting the variables for the `nocompl in  [im,ie,sm,se]` test in your list comprehension? The `for` loop sets different names: `for v1,e1,v2,e2 in`

Comment: At any rate, list comprehensions in Python 2 share all local names with the current scope, so if you do use `for im,ie,sm,se in` in the loop, then `sm` will be set and interfere with your import.

Comment: Uhm, I'm sorry for that. I rewrote only the most important parts of my code and to make my code more readable I changed the names of variables like `im`,`ie`,`sm`,`se` for `v1`,`e1` and so on, but not everywhere. Thereby @MartijnPieters has found a reason of my problem. Now the code works correctly. Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, there is no difference in how `zip()` operates with 2 or more lists. Instead, your list comprehension assigned to the name `sm` in the loop, while at the same time you used the name `sm` to reference the `statsmodels` module.

Your simpler two-list version doesn't do this, so the name `sm` isn't rebound, and you don't run into the issue.

In Python 2, names used in the list comprehension are part of the local scope:

```
>>> foo
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
NameError: name 'foo' is not defined
>>> [foo for foo in 'bar']
['b', 'a', 'r']
>>> foo
'r'
```

Here the name `foo` was set in the `for` loop of the list comprehension, and the name is still available after the loop.

Either rename your import, or rename your loop variables.